# what is the problem for this WARN Error: Icon intersect not found when run Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to understand what it causing this error,

`WARN Error: Icon intersect not found when run Angular unit test`

Google around but no any related result found. If someone know how to fix this, please share how to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you could share the code causing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.